# Insert into binary search tree. Nodes replacing

Tags: c++, insert, binary-search-tree

I use this bit of code to create a new node and insert it into a binary search tree. It inserts the root properly, the same with its first right and left children but anything after that seems to replace the already existing child.

For example:

```
     7
  2     15
```

If I insert 10 now it will replace 15 instead of becomming its left child.

```
Node * createNode(Element elem)
{
    Node * newNode = new Node;
    newNode->elem = elem;
    newNode->left = nullptr;
    newNode->right = nullptr;
    newNode->parent = nullptr;
    return newNode;
}

bool insertElem(BST & tree, Element elem)
{
    Node * newNode = createNode(elem);
    if (!tree.root)
    {
        tree.root = newNode;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return insertElem(newNode, tree.root);
    }
}

bool insertElem(Node * node, Node * root)
{
    if (node->elem.key == root->elem.key) return false; // already exists
    if (node->elem.key > root->elem.key) // goes to the right
    {
        if (root->right) insertElem(node, root->right);
        node->parent = root;
        root->right = node;
        return true;
    }
    if (node->elem.key < root->elem.key) // goes to the left
    {
        if (root->left) insertElem(node, root->left);
        node->parent = root;
        root->left = node;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Which debugger have you used to trace the steps when inserting a new node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic for left and right decension should *not* be blindly overwriting `root->left` and/or `root->right`. Nor should you allocate a new node until  you *know* you're going to insert into the tree. Finally, reference to point (or pointer to pointer, but this is C++, after all) makes the algorithm considerably easier to understand:

The general recursive insertion looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;

    Node(int arg) : value(arg), left(), right()
    {
    }
};

void insertElem(Node *& root, int value)
{
    if (root)
    {
        if (value < root->value )
            insertElem(root->left, value);
        else if (root->value < value)
            insertElem(root->right, value);
        // else equivalent, do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        root = new Node(value);
    }
}

void inorder(const Node* root)
{
    if (!root)
        return;

    inorder(root->left);
    std::cout << root->value << ' ';
    inorder(root->right);
}

void delete_tree(Node *& root)
{
    if (root)
    {
        delete_tree(root->right);
        delete_tree(root->left);
        delete root;
        root = nullptr;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1,10);

    Node *root = nullptr;
    for (size_t i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        int value = dist(rng);
        std::cout << value << ' ';
        insertElem(root, value);
    }
    std::cout.put('\n');

    inorder(root);
    std::cout.put('\n');

    delete_tree(root);
}
```

**Output** (example)

```
5 7 6 1 3 5 7 3 1 1 
1 3 5 6 7
```

Notice this is an example that both demonstrates the tree built correctly (thus proper sort order), but also elimination of duplicates.

What makes this work is the pointers descending as *references* to the actual node pointers of the tree, including the initial root pointer which starts as `nullptr` in `main()`.

---

To allow duplicates, all that must be done is a few small changes to the insertion routine:

```
void insertElem(Node *& root, int value)
{
    if (root)
    {
        if (value < root->value )
            insertElem(root->left, value);
        else // no right test, just descend
            insertElem(root->right, value);
    }
    else
    {
        root = new Node(value);
    }
}
```

Changing only that a sample output looks like this:

```
2 9 4 2 2 4 7 2 5 6 
2 2 2 2 4 4 5 6 7 9
```

Adapt as-needed.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how recursion works in this case. How and when is *left/*right set for the parent and how to set a parent for the newly inserted node? Also for my environment I had to make a small fix and give Node a default constructor (int arg = -1).